# Can you define RowDefinition in style xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="7.5*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and I would like to define the `Height` in a Style or in a variable in the app.xaml.

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource myHeight}"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource myHeight2}"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Is this possible? I have tried but I get an error.

The reason I want to achieve this is that on small devices I need to change the row height.

I would appreciate any tips or suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean changing the height by the size of  device screen ?

Comment: Do you mean changing height for phone and tablet separately?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT when we load the app we detect whether is a small device or big device and load the relevant styles and I would like to define in a static resource the height of the row. I cannot go code behind I wanted to find a xaml solution to it. I hope it makes sense   eg    <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource MyHeight"></RowDefinition> . see edit question

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi see comment above

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use DynamicResources here instead of Static and just creating these resources at runtime? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic

Comment: @FreakyAli Happy to use Dynamic resources instead of static however does it mean I need to build the grid in code? I cannot  move the creation of the grid to code I just need to adjust the height of the row but in xaml. Do you  have some where I can adjust the rowdefinition using dynamic resources

Comment: You do not have to move your Grid anywhere, All you have to do is create these Resources at Runtime and give them values and use the `DynamicResource` keyword instead of `StaticResource` to access them. If you want i can quickly give you an example.

Comment: @FreakyAli it would help greatly if you could.

Comment: @developer9969 Hi , I have updated an answer , you can have a look .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a model to `ContentPage` , then `Grid` can use binded data by model and row height can be setted by model data (contain row height paramaters).

For example , create a sample ViewModel(**RowHeightClass**) as follow :

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;    

public class RowHeightClass 
{
    public GridLength rowFirstHeight { set; get; }
    public GridLength rowSecondHeight { set; get; }

    public RowHeightClass()
    {
        // here can add code set by device screen 
        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        double screenheight = mainDisplayInfo.Height;

        rowFirstHeight = new GridLength(DeviceDisplay * 0.2);

        rowSecondHeight = new GridLength(DeviceDisplay * 0.4);
    }
}
```

Binding it in ContentPage :

```
RowHeightClass rowHeightClass = new RowHeightClass();

BindingContext = rowHeightClass;
```

Used in XAML :

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding rowFirstHeight}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding rowSecondHeight}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             BackgroundColor="Blue" />

    <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="0"
             BackgroundColor="Red" />

    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</Grid>
```

Note : You can modify the constructor method of `RowHeightClass` to add method to set needed height by the size of device screen .

==================================Update=====================================

Using `StaticResource` also can set the heigh of row . Add a [Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#override-resources) for Grid or Application as follow :

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:Double x:Key="SmallScreenRowheight">200</x:Double>
            <x:Double x:Key="LargeScreenRowheight">400</x:Double>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource SmallScreenRowheight}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource LargeScreenRowheight}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             BackgroundColor="Blue" />

    <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="0"
             BackgroundColor="Red" />

    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Jiang. Thank you so much for your reply and help. I just now want this code not to be part of the ViewModel but the view codebehind as does not belong to the viewModel. Can I bind it in the view codebehind?

Comment: @developer9969 Yes , u can . I have updated the answer .